# How do I solve this ODE $y'(x) + y(x) = \frac{1}{1+ e^{-x}} $

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I tried to solve this ODE, but I couldn't find the particular solution. With $x\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$y'(x) + y(x) = \frac{1}{1+ e^{-x}} $$ 
So far I got the homogeneous one:
$$ y_h(x)= C e^{-x} $$

Unfortunately I don't know the technical terms in English. I would really appreciate if you could write down what to do instead of telling me to try "this" or "that" method.

The answer is  $$y(x)=Ce^{-x} +1 -e^{-x} \ln(1+e^{x}) $$

Comment: For reference, you have a linear first order ODE:
http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like in the homogeneous case, multiply both sides by $e^{x}$ to get
$$
(e^{x}y(x))'=\frac{e^{x}}{1+e^{-x}}
$$
Integrate both sides,
$$
e^{x}y(x)=c+\int^{x}\frac{e^{s}}{1+e^{-s}}ds
=c+\int^{x}\frac{e^{2s}}{1+e^{s}}ds
$$$$=c+\int^{x}\left(e^{s}-\frac{e^{s}}{1+e^{s}}\right)ds
=c+e^{x}-\ln{(1+e^{x})}
$$

So $y(x)=ce^{-x}+1-e^{-x}\ln(1+e^{x})$

Comment: Nice one. I didn't get it at first, but then I saw that you multiplied the fraction inside the integral by $\frac{e^{x}}{e^{x}}$, then at the end just divided the whole equation by $e^{x}$. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hint thats a first order linear differentiation equation. Here the $IF =e^{\int 1.dx}=e^x $ now use the formula that solution of such equations is  given by $y.IF=\int IF (\frac {e^x}{1+e^x}$ in general $y.IF=\int IF (q(x) )dx$ is the solution of $y'+y=q (x) $ you can prove it by multiplying by $e^x $ on both sides

Answer (score 0):

Linear equations like this one can be solved by variation of the constant. As you figured out the homogeneous solution is $y_h(x) = ce^{-x}$, thus for the ansatz $y(x) = c(x)e^{-x}$ we obtain

$$ y'+y = c'e^{-x} -ce^{-x} + ce^{-x} \overset{!}{=} \frac
{1}{1+e^{-x}} \implies c = \int \frac{e^x}{1+e^{-x}} dx $$

Compute the integral and you are done.